# Adding new party to the existing network

Tags: corda

I have a corda network [(corda as system service)](https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html) (v3.1) running in `devMode`, the network structure goes like:

1. Party A
2. Party B
3. Party C
4. NotaryA (simple notary)
5. NotaryB (validating notary)
6. Oracle

The network is running perfectly fine until I try to add one more party to the network (Party D). Steps how I try to add new party:

1. Generate nodeInfo, certificates etc using network-bootstrapper tool for new party
2. Place the node folder parallel to the other node folders and add required cordapp to the cordapps folder inside the newly added party
3. Share the nodeinfo to all other nodes and vice-versa

This didn't work, probably because newly added node has a different network parameter file then other nodes and has no information about the notary nodes.

I tried the other way:

1. Keep `node.conf` of all the nodes along with the node.conf of new node and generate nodeInfo, network-parameters etc for all nodes.
2. Place the folder of the new node parallel to other nodes and replace network-parameter, additional-nodeinfo folder and nodeinfo files of old nodes with the newly created files and folders.
3. Add required cordapps to `node/cordapps` folders
   But this way also it didn't work.

Can you help me with correct steps for adding new node to the existing network?

Comment: I've given a link below. If you can't solve it using that, drop me a comment and I can help you out further :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrapper can only generate information for a set of nodes that are on the same machine. If a node needs to be added to a bootstrapped network, all the nodes need to be collected back together on the same machine.

The instructions for adding a node to a bootstrapped network are available here: https://docs.corda.net/head/network-bootstrapper.html#adding-a-new-node-to-the-network.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I was able to add new party successfully.
Can we add notary/oracle node similarly?

Comment: Yes. You use the same process for adding a notary/oracle node. The notary will need a notary block in its `node.conf` file (e.g. `notary : { validating : false }`).